# Is there any way to accept binary data type like pdf in serverless?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, file-upload, serverless

I am facing the issue like the following:
When uploading a pdf file in vue.js to serverless node.js application, file content is broken.
Because the serverless parses binary data type incorrectly, it happens the issue.
How can I accept binary data type like pdf correctly or other method to solve the issue?

```
// Vue.js
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileObj);
axios.post(API_ENDPOINT + '/upload', formData).then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
})
```

```
// Serverless Express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.files.file) // Uploaded tmp file - It has broken content
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty). I will provide the middleware in the following snippet of code

```
const { Form } = require('multiparty')

function formDataParser(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.is('multipart/form-data')) {
        next();
        return;
    }

    const form = new Form();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Could not parse multipart form.'
            });

            return;
        }

        const fieldsKeys = Object.keys(fields);
        for (const fieldKey of fieldsKeys) {
            fields[fieldKey] = fields[fieldKey][0];
        }

        req.form = {
            fields,
            files
        }
        
        next();
    });
}

module.exports = formDataParser;
```

I suggest not to attach this middleware as a global one but instead use it only on specific routes that need it. With the provided solution you can access form fields in the following way:

```
req.form.fields.somefield
```